# Referencing a Link to a particular inner php

Tags: php, href

I am a newbie exploring php , kindly pardon me if i look silly also since i exactly don't know how to title this, i titled what i felt to be relative .

I have a login form which have inputs email,password and usertype dropdown

Based on usertype selected, table will be selected in db

Logged in user will be redirected to account.php which looks like below

```
<?php require_once("header.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("top_bar.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("left_side_nav.php"); ?>
<!-- MAIN CONTENTS START -->
<?php 
if(isset($_SESSION['login_type']) && $_SESSION['login_type'] = 'admin')
{
require_once("a_inner_dash.php"); 
}
else if(isset($_SESSION['login_type']) && $_SESSION['login_type'] = 'user')
{
require_once("u_inner_dash.php"); 
}   
else if(isset($_SESSION['login_type']) && $_SESSION['login_type'] = 'accountant')
{
require_once("ac_inner_dash.php"); 
}   
?> 
<!-- MAIN CONTENTS END -->
<?php require_once("footer.php"); ?>
```

The file `"left_side_nav.php"` is as below

```
<!-- sidebar menu: : style can be found in sidebar.less -->
<ul class="sidebar-menu">
    <li class="header">MAIN NAVIGATION</li>

        <li>
          <a href="account.php">
            <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> <span>Account</span>
          </a>
        </li>
         <li>
          <a href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-male"></i> <span>Menu1</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-child"></i> <span>Menu2</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-group"></i> <span>Menu3</span>
          </a>
        </li>
       </ul>
</section>
    <!-- /.sidebar -->
</aside>
```

Now my issue is, When i logged in as admin and i click a menu item for instance Menu1 the result should be on `"a_inner_dash.php"` and if i logged in as User and click on menu item the result should be on `"u_inner_dash.php"` and as you see in account.php it's just a part in a webpage

i tried and couldn't sort out a way . Kindly help me please

**Note :** The logged in user type is correctly been detected and the correct main content URL is been loaded. The issue is i don't know how to reference the menu from navbar to here which is a part of webpage

Comment: Looks like you didn't start the session using `session_start()`. Did you?

Comment: @PraveenKumar i did its in header.php which i included in account.php

Comment: Strange... What exactly is your problem?

Comment: try to debug it using `var_dump($_SESSION);` to see if your session is present, and the values are as expected

Comment: @Burki , Ya it is , my question is how to give href to output inside another php . like here if i click on menu1 in left_side_nav.php , it should output in a_inner_dash.php if the session is in admin or in u_inner_dash.php if the session is in user

Comment: what should happen (from what i understand) is that after clicking the link, the new page should read the `$_SESSION` and load the include scripts depending on the value. So: after clicking the link, in the new page, is the session available?

Comment: If the session is available and correct, things should work as you planend them. But maybe i just don't understand your question?